# Online 3D plotting tool for systems of linear equations in three unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, systems-of-equations

I was trying to visualize how systems of linear equations in three unknowns work but failed miserably and I started to look for an online tool which would allow me to plot all three equations but surprisingly I could not find one.

Does anyone know of such precious tool?

Comment: wolframalpha e.g. [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot3d+%283x%2By%2B5z%2C-x-y-7z%2C-x%2By%29 ]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Geogebra 3D. It is not an online tool but it might be just what you need.[geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/)

I know they also have an online version of the 2D version but I do not know if they have one of the 3D version yet. Please check the site.